# setContentView cannot resolve symbol 'splash'

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

I tried to make a splash screen in my project
with this code:

```
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.R;

    public class splash extends BaseActivity {
    private MediaPlayer splashsound;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.***activity_splash***);
        splashsound = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.***train_wav***);
        splashsound.start();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(splash.this, LaunchActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        },5000);
    }
}
```

I have the following errors:

> 1. cannot resolve symbol 'activity_splash'
> 2. cannot resolve symbol
>          'train_wav'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You imported the wrong `R` class. `android.R` is for system resources. Change your import to

```
import whatever.your.packagename.is.R;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you have added `***` but it should be:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        splashsound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.train_wav);
```

Also:

```
import android.R;
```

Seems to be wrong. Try removing this line and let Android Studio show which choices in imports you have. It should be something like this:

```
import app.package.name.R;
```

Comment: OP is trying to format the problematic pieces, which obviously doesn't work in a code block. Android Studio would complain that `***activity_splash***` can't be found if OP actually used the asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

Change below code :

```
setContentView(R.layout.***activity_splash***);
```

to :

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
```

and if your layout name have *** just remove *** an try again .